# Watir and Rspec script does nothing

Tags: watir

I am new new in Watir, Rspec testing and i am just getting familiar with it. I found one test on internet, combination of Rspec and watir but id does nothing. it throws error require 'spec' does not exist. I have rspec 2.12 installed. Did I miss something here, do i need to install something? Rspec scripts are working as well as watir but this combination not.

```
require 'watir'
require 'spec'

describe "Google" do

  before :all do
    @browser = Watir::Browser.new
    @browser.goto "http://google.com"
  end

  it "has word 'Google' on main page" do
    @browser.text.should include("Google")
  end

  it "has word 'Bing' as it's title" do
    @browser.title.should == "Bing"
  end

  after :all do
    @browser.close
  end

end
```

Answer (score 2):

"I found one test on internet" does not help. Please provide link to the page.

Also, you did not say how you run the script. As far as I remember, to run RSpec 1.x scripts you had to do `spec file_name.rb`, and with RSpec 2.x you have to do `rspec file_name.rb`. That could be the problem.

Comment: Thank you fro the answer, i was running it with ruby file_name.rb. rspec file_name.rb resolved my issue. Thanks again